# Windows 8.1 already activated but PC Settings asks for activation

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, windows-activation

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 laptop, which came with Windows 8.1. I upgraded my RAM to 16 GB and had no problem for weeks.  Later, I had to uninstall my CorelDraw program, but I also uninstalled Corel Graphics Windows Shell Extention and Lenovo Pokki start menu.  That messed my laptop and I got watermark in my Desktop.

I had to reinstall the CorelDraw to fix that watermark.  It shows Activated in "System", but every 30 minutes, PC Settings pop up and says I have to activate.  When I click "Activate Windows Online" it says: "Windows Can't Activate. Try again later."

I already tried to enable/disable Secure Boot from Motherboard BIOS settings and also I used,

`slmgr /ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx`

and

`slmgr /ato`

command to activate.  Every time it says Windows is activated successfully but still I get that PC Settings Annoying message to Activate Windows.  I really don't want to use One Key Recovery on my laptop, I appreciate any help to fix this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the phone activation.  This will allow you to talk to a human

Comment: it wont help if the computer has come into a "undefined" state where it Thinks its both activated and not activated. This happens sometimes and the only way out is to completely deactivate the computer (so any lingering activation files are deleted) and then reactivate computer.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure CorelDraw and Corel Graphics are uninstalled. (see later why this is important)
use slmgr.vbs /upk to deactivate the computer.
Then run sfc /scannow to ensure any files are not damaged in the system.
Then try reactivate windows using "change Product key" and entering the Product key.

Note that you CANNOT use the Product key that is reported by certain "Product key recovery" Tools because computer manufacturers often install a preactivated windows that is using a generic key & a special certificate for activation.

What you need to do to get your Product key, the real one, is to check the ACPI records for a flag called "MSDM". This can be checked using numerious ACPI Tools found on the internet.

I would suggest uninstall CorelDraw and other programs Before reactivating computer using the above instructions, because those programs apparently affect the activation status of the system (propably because you changed RAM and CorelDraw uses some driver that affects the activation status).
By first uninstalling CorelDraw and Corel Graphics, you ensure your new activation will activate without these installed.

You might get a message that the Product key is invalid and you need to buy a new one or "use the automated phone solution". Then select "use the automated phone solution", and do the activation over the phone.

Comment: Oh thank you, before doing what you said i have run sfc /scannow
Here is the results: 
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.

Comment: Check the file c:\windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log, check which files are missing, and then fetch them from a good source. (you can for example download Windows 8.1 iso from Microsofts website, extract the ISO and find the missing files). Replace the files in their original location with the known good files. Then rerun sfc /scannow to "rearm" the protection. To open CBS.log, you might need to get to properties, take ownership of file, and then give yourself read rights.